# Change color of SVG image defined in CSS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I have an input box with an SVG circle inside of it:

```
input{
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30'><circle cx='15' cy='15' r='10' /></svg>")  no-repeat;
}
```

Using Javascript how can I change the color of the circle to red (say when a user enters something illegal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the svg as a css background as mentioned you will have to have a separate class with a red background svg that you can swap out

```
<input class="a" onchange="checkValue(event)" type="text" name="a">

function checkValue(event){
  var input = event.target; 
  if(input.value.length<2){
    input.className = "error";
  }else{
    input.className = "";
  }
}

input{
  background:background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30'><circle cx='15' cy='15' r='10' fill="black" /></svg>")  no-repeat;
}

.error{
  background:background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30'><circle cx='15' cy='15' r='10' fill="red" /></svg>")  no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: You're are welcome. Look at inline svg if you want to just change the fill in js

Answer (score 1):

As i read your description,
1) You need to add style in javascript event base on your functionality [like on change or on form submit where ever you want to validate]

2) Please fix minor change "`fill='#f00'`" in below css:

```
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' fill='#f00'><circle cx='15' cy='15' r='10' /></svg>")  no-repeat;
```

Comment: Correct. So how do I change `fill` from within Javascript? Alternatively, how do I change the circle from hidden to shown (since the circle doesn't always need to be visible)?

Comment: Just put 1 extra class in css apply style already given in Answer then append this class in input using JavaScript.